# How disable "unexpected" scrolling behavior in small frames

Tags: frames, scrolling

I find the way that the cursor scrolls in small frames unintuitive. When I press `C-p` I expect the cursor to move up a line. Instead, in the org-mode file below, right before the cursor gets to the `#+RESULTS` line it jumps up several lines to the displayed image. Maybe this is a bug?

[image: weird scrolling in org-mode]

I experience the same behavior in a small frame containing a shell buffer.

[image: weird scrolling in *shell*]

If not, and this is the intended scrolling behavior in small frames, is there a way to disable it to get *line-by-line* scrolling?

Comment: P.S. for people using compton with recordmydesktop (e.g. via the excellent camcorder.el), use the -CG flags to disable dark shadowing in the recording window.

Comment: P.P.S. I used `convert scrolling-in-shell.gif +dither -quality 60% -resize '600x400' -layers optimize -colors 24 scrolling-in-shell-2.gif` to make my gif files not 30 Mb. Hopefully, that saves someone a few minutes of headache... and makes up for any headaches induced by the gifs themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed the `smooth-scrolling` package from `MELPA`. Removing it eliminated this particular scrolling behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Adjust option **`scroll-margin`** to your liking.  (You might also want to look at option `scroll-step`.)

> Number of lines of margin at the top and bottom of a window.
>   Recenter the window whenever point gets within this many lines
>   of the top or bottom of the window.

Comment: Hmm... I played around `scroll-margin`, `scroll-step`, `scroll-conservatively`, `auto-window-vscroll`, and `scroll-preserve-screen-position` and didn't see any improvement.

Comment: It turns out that I had the smooth-scrolling package installed from Melpa and it was advising my cursor functions. It's amazing what you can find out from `C-h k`.